# Ruby. Crack gem. -- in `<main>': undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError) --

Tags: ruby, xml-parsing, nomethoderror

Dear stackoverflow community,

Beginner's question: 
Why do I get the following error?

```
scraper_sample_2.rb:7:in `<main>': undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
>Exit code: 1
```

Here's my code (copied from a ruby's intro guide):

```
require "rubygems"
require "crack"
require "open-uri"

URL = "http://www.recovery.gov/pages/GetXmlData.aspx?data=recipientHomeMap"

Crack::XML.parse(open(URL).read)["totals"]["state"].each do |state|
    puts ["id", "awarded", "received", "jobs"].map{|f| state[f]}.join(",")
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Because `Crack::XML.parse(open(URL).read)["totals"]` is `nil`. Try to split the call you do on line 7 on several lines and debug each call separately. Maybe the answer you get is not what you expect.

Answer (score 0):

Given the format of the xml returned from [your source](http://www.recovery.gov/pages/GetXmlData.aspx?data=recipientHomeMap), `Crack::XML.parse(open(URL).read)["totals"]` will, as Ivaylo said, return `nil`.  The format of the xml must have changed, as `totals` are now within `/map/view`.

To get the expected output, change your code to:

```
Crack::XML.parse(open(URL).read)["map"]["view"]["totals"]["state"].each do |state|
    puts ["id", "awarded", "received", "jobs"].map{|f| state[f]}.join(",")
end
```